# Android speech to text using listview

Tags: android, listview, speech-to-text

The code below is used to convert speech to text on an android app. This code works when the speech button is pressed and whatever you say is transferred into text.
When the speech function closes, the the text is showing.
If you hit the speech button again, the previous text is cleared and the new text shows on the page. What i want to do is everytime i click the speak button, i want to show the word on the page.. then if i click the speak button again, i want the next word to appear under the first word in a list format.
i am looking to use listview but am struggling. here is the original code and the code i am trying to write to make it a listview. can anyone assist?

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/speak"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private TextView txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                txtText.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            txtText.setText(text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry! should have been more clear.
when the speak button is pressed and i say a word, the word appears on the screen. when i press the speak button again the first word disappears and the second word i say appears on the screen. What i am trying to do is show all the words on the screen in a list view and have a clear button that clears the list when i want. The question is.. what is the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your onActivityResult, you are overriding your TextView with the first word only(index 0).
You must iterate through the String array list like so:

```
    String words = "";
    for ( String word : text ) {
        words += " " + word;
    }
    txtText.setText(words);
```

And here's a nice article to help you implement your ListView:
[ListView tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

So now when you figured that out you add the words value in the listview.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers